# Where are all the pre-installed autorelease pools in iPhone applications?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uikit

I am wondering how many there are, and where they are. As I have seen in a Stanford Vid, there is one autorelease pool installed in the event loop of an iPhone App. But I think I missed the point where exactly that is? And are there any other autorelease pools that I should know about?

Answer (score 4):

in main.m file
(in X-code it is in "Other Sources" folder)

Answer (score 2):

The application's autorelease pool drains every pass through the run loop. You can add your own pool anywhere you want, if you have a big loop that creates a lot of objects it can be a good idea to put a pool there to limit memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

Every thread that you create needs its own autorelease pool. Check the documentation for `NSThread` for details.

Your main application thread, by default, will use the one created in `main.m`. Unless you're doing a bunch of big operations like Marc Charbonneau said, you generally don't need to create others. And if you're really doing that many operations, it might be a good idea to do them in a separate thread anyway.